# Método de extensão(Wait() e Status()) não funciona

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Isso aqui não está funcionando(apenas as linhas do Wait() e do Status())

```
try
            {
                string url = $"http://localhost:2710/api/faturamento/{IdUsuario}/{IdGaragem}";
                var uri = string.Format(url);
                var response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

                response.Wait(); // AQUI DÁ O ERRO

                while (response.Status != System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)// AQUI DÁ O ERRO
                {

                }

                var desvio = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DesvioFaturamento>>(response);
                return desvio;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string erro = ex.Message;

                return null;
            }
```

dá esse erro:

> "string" não contém uma definição para "Wait" e não foi possível
>   encontrar nenhum método de extensão "Wait"  que aceite um primeiro
>   argumento do tipo "string" (há uma diretiva de uso ou referência de
>   assembly ausente?)
>
> "string" não contém uma definição para "Status" e não foi possível
>   encontrar nenhum método de extensão "Status"  que aceite um primeiro
>   argumento do tipo "string" (há uma diretiva de uso ou referência de
>   assembly ausente?)

P.S. Tenho outro projeto Xamarin.Forms que essas linhas estão funcionando e tenho as mesmas referências.

**EDIT1**

Esse aqui tá funcionando

```
public async Task<List<LiberacaoItensGrid>> GetDataGrid(double id)
        {
            try
            {
                //var client = new HttpClient();
                //string url = $"http://www.inetglobal.com.br/autorizador/api/getliberaitens/{id}";

         //var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                //var itenslib = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LiberacaoItensGrid>>(response);

                var client = new HttpClient();
                string url = $"http://www.inetglobal.com.br/autorizador/api/getliberaitens/{id}";
                var response = client.GetStringAsync(url);

                response.Wait(); // use assim ou com o while ....

                while (response.Status != System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {

                }
                var itenslib = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LiberacaoItensGrid>>(response.Result.ToString());

                return itenslib.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Onde está a definição/declaração do método de extensão?

Comment: @LINQ, como assim, onde está a definição? Não entendi. Vou fazer uma edição e mostrar um outro projeto que não tem erro algum, da forma que tá vou postar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `Wait` é um método de **`Task`** e `respose` **é uma string**.

Perceba que no primeiro código tem a *keyword*  `await`, isso faz com que a task seja resolvida e que a variável `response` seja do tipo **`string`**.

Seu código está assim

```
var response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

Deveria ser

```
var response = client.GetStringAsync(uri);
```